# creating iOS app for Apple TV using titanium appcelerator

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have created iOS app using appcelerator titanium I want to know if this created app will run on Apple TV or will need to create separate app for Apple TV ?
The idea is to have single ipa that supports iPhone, iPad and Apple TV.
I googled but couldn't find any document where app can be created using Appcelerator for Apple TV.

Comment: may I know the reason for down vote ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open request ticket at https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19570

So currently it is not supported

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add it just like using the watchOS target in your app. It may require a bit more tooling when talking about resources, but in general they could be merged together.